# FileNotFoundException- Copying a file from my local to server using java

Tags: java

I am trying to copy a excel from local to pjt workspace using JAVA..

my piece of code is:

```
public void copy(String filepath,String newFilePath) throws IOException
{File oldFile = new File(filepath);
    File newFile = new File(newFilePath);   
    try{
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(oldFile, newFile);
       }
```

filepath is: `C:\fakepath\exceldata.xls(file path)`

newFilePath is : `D:/Workspace/Pjt/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/bench/files/2013-10-16` (Its directory in my eclipse workspace)

It is working when my tomcat server and file are in same machine..
But, it is not working when I tried to upload a file from different machine.

In this case, i am getting the error that source file is not found (`FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION`.)

Please help me out...
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you..

Comment: You cannot access file on a remote machine by using the path. That would be a security breach. You need to upload them, and get an `InputStream` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `request.getContextPath()`
see this oracle link for more [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) also this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) will be also useful

Answer (score 0):

In case of a remote server, try adding the IP address to the filepath, like this

```
File f = new File("//192.168.1.123/pathtofile/data.xls");// 192.168.1.123 is the ip of the computer which has the file to be copied
```

Answer (score 0):

fakepath?

You mean you are trying to upload the file and came up with such exception,right?
File upload will produce stream for the server to process ,so you can not get the path in your local machine in the remote machine.

So try commons fileupload or the other upload components.Or just use servlet is ok,just a little complicated.

The following page may be useful:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html